# Field System.MulticastDelegate._invocationCount is not available c#

Tags: c#, forms, error-handling, user-controls, event-handling

I've tried to use event from an userControl to a form, but when I'm creating it in a form constructor I've an issue. I don't know where is a fail. There is my code.

UserControl

```
public GameField()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        button.Click += Button_Clicked;
    }

public event EventHandler ButtonClicked;
private void Button_Clicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (this.ButtonClicked != null) this.ButtonClicked(sender, e);
    }
```

Form

```
GameField gameField = new GameField(); //Instance of the derived class UserControl       

    public Form1()
    {            
        InitializeComponent();
        gameField.ButtonClicked += new EventHandler(this.btn_Click);
    }

    private void btn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
```

There is an issue
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tAo5m.png)

Comment: what happens when the button in user control is clicked?

Comment: It refers to `void Button_Clicked`.

Comment: i meant to ask does it not hit `btn_Click`?

Comment: Shouldn’t it be `button.Click += Button_Clicked;` in `GameField`? You’re missing an underscore character.

Comment: When I set breakpoint to `btn_Click` and hit the button, nothing happens.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you wanted to subscribe to `Button_Clicked` instead of `ButtonClicked` in `GameField`.

```
button.Click += Button_Clicked;
```

**Edit**

I see, I have a hunch that you have two instances of `GameField`. The one that you added through the forms designer, probably named `gameField1` and the one that you added in code to your form called `gameField`.

If you open `Form1.Designer.cs` can you see a `gameField1` in there (or whatever name you gave when you added it through the designer)?

Can you try the following:

```
gameField1.ButtonClicked += new EventHandler(btn_Clicked); // name can be other than gameField1, gameField1 is just the automatically generated name by VS
```

Comment: Yeah it should be, but I'm sorry that was typing error. But the problem is still the same...

Comment: Amazing! Thx you very much! Now it works correctly... :)